# In Mongo what is the difference between $near and $nearSphere?

Tags: mongodb

I read the docs and its not very clear what the difference is between the two.

The only difference I found is that in nearSphere it explicitly says that Mongo calculates distances for $nearSphere using spherical geometry. But this is achievable using $near as well is it not?

Comment: I have the exact same interrogation. Did you find anything ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The keyword is `sphere` to differentiate between [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) and [$nearSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/).

As you are aware, `$nearSphere` is stated to calculate distance using spherical geometry. This is related to the Earth [map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) ([distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Distortion)). Where [MongoDB 2d indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/) is based on [Cartesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) and [MongoDB 2dsphere indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) is based on [Geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_grid).

Enough theory, let's use some examples. Let's say we have two documents as below:

```
db.map.insert({ "_id": "Westfield London", "location": [ -0.22157, 51.507176 ] });
db.map.insert({ "_id": "Green Lanes Shopping Centre", "location": [ -0.098092, 51.576198 ] });
```

The manual for both operators specify that we can use:

- `2dsphere` index for location data defined as [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) points
- `2d` index for location data defined as [legacy coordinate pairs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-legacy-coordinate-pairs)

**Index: 2dsphere , Query: GeoJSON**

```
db.map.createIndex({"location": "2dsphere"});

db.map.find({"location":{"$nearSphere":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[ -0.127748, 51.507333 ] }}}});

db.map.find({"location":{"$near":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[ -0.127748, 51.507333 ]}}}});
```

In this case, both queries will return the same result, because the index is stored in `2dsphere`.

Result:

```
[ /* $nearSphere */
    {"_id" : "Westfield London"},
    {"_id" : "Green Lanes Shopping Centre"}
]
[ /* $near */
    {"_id" : "Westfield London"},
    {"_id" : "Green Lanes Shopping Centre"}
]
```

**Index: 2d , Query: Legacy Coordinates**

```
db.map.createIndex({"location": "2d"});

db.map.find({"location":{"$nearSphere":[ -0.127748, 51.507333 ]}});

db.map.find({"location":{"$near":[ -0.127748, 51.507333 ]}});
```

This is where the distinction happens, the result for `$nearSphere` is calculated spherically despite the index, while `$near` is calculated in flat projection.

Result:

```
[ /* $nearSphere */
    {"_id" : "Westfield London"},
    {"_id" : "Green Lanes Shopping Centre"}
]
[ /* $near */
    {"_id" : "Green Lanes Shopping Centre"},
    {"_id" : "Westfield London"}
]
```

See [gist: JS test script](https://gist.github.com/sindbach/973e152d1974dcd8fd65fdee70a41d0a) of the above example. This was tested using MongoDB v3.4.4.

Also see [Geospatial Indexes and Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/).