# Node JS Mongo $near not working with nested field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I've been working on a simple search using the $near operator but have recently changed my data so the 2dsphere location index is now in the nested field `properties.location` instead of just `location`. I am using the Node JS mongo driver and the search worked fine when the index was not nested inside the `properties` object using the following query, but returns nothing now:

**Previous working query:**

```
dbObject.collection("scrapedTimes").find({
            location: {
                $near: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: "Point" ,
                        coordinates: [lngBound, latBound]
                    },
                    $minDistance: 0,
                    $maxDistance: 100000
                }
            }

})
```

**Current query that returns nothing:**

```
dbObject.collection("scrapedTimes").find({
            "properties.location": {
                $near: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: "Point" ,
                        coordinates: [lngBound, latBound]
                    },
                    $minDistance: 0,
                    $maxDistance: 100000
                }
            }

})
```

I have executed this same nested query in Mongo Compass and it seems to work fine so I think it might be a problem with the Node JS driver? I'm quite new to Mongo so there might be something obvious I'm missing here but I just can't get Node to return any results...

Thanks for your time and suggestions,

Josh

[image: DB layout]
[image: 2dsphere index]

Comment: have you tried changing `$near` to `$nearSphere` in your query...leaving everything else the same...

Comment: Awesome!, please upvote my answer ey... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$near` to `$nearSphere`, there's a difference between the two which mainly relates to calculations using spherical geometry. `$near` will use flat geometry and won't work because of the `2dSphere` index on the nested document.

Check this out for the difference between the two...

[In Mongo what is the difference between $near and $nearSphere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287374/in-mongo-what-is-the-difference-between-near-and-nearsphere#answer-43796889)